# React native layout fixed width and stretch remaining space

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How can I make something like this in react-native ?

In the right I want a component that has a fixed width, and in the left taking all the remaining space another component.

[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try this:

```
  <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
    <View style={{
      backgroundColor: 'blue',
      flexGrow: 1,
    }}>
      <Text>Fluid</Text>
    </View>
    <View style={{
      backgroundColor: 'red',
      width: 100,
    }}>
      <Text>Fixed</Text>        
    </View>
  </View>
```

Comment: Nice. I did not know about `flexGrow` property. Ty

Comment: I'm having problems trying to use this solution ... maybe it's my code ... but it's happening to me that if I put a lot of text (replacing "Fluid") ... the column sizes don't work ... please help

Comment: Thank  you! Saved me a bunch of hassle. Couldn't figure it out until I saw this.

Comment: even I was not aware of flexGrow property thank you.

Comment: I also had problems with this code ... I had to change the `flexgrow` to `flex` to get it to work properly.  Also, if you are testing this inside a `FlatList` you have to restart the application to see the effects of styling changes - just a note in case other people see weirdness happening inside a `FlatList`

Comment: This didn't work for me when I had a lot of text in the blue container. It would grow and take up as much space as it could. But having `flex: 1, flexGrow: 1` on the blue container works for me.